# Sending image using udp fail

Tags: c#

I sending bitmap using udp.
I see in the sending that all bytes are sent. 
but on the receiving side I see that the number of bytes are less than the number of byte I sent.

what can be the reason  to this ? 
if I send small image I see that  it's OK .. (less bytes to send )

i sending block of 1500 bytes.

Comment: well the reason is that you are doing something wrong. Put the test code and demonstrate issue.

Comment: You know UDP makes no guarantees that your packets will not be lost? If you care, you should use TCP.

Comment: While sending data using UDP some packets might be dropped, so you might want to create some confirmation mechanism

Comment: yes I know - but this I sent from localhost to localhost. and I can't unfortunately add the code.

Comment: Does it always have the same number of missing bytes?

Comment: no, always different number of bytes on the receiving side

Comment: If you can't post code, we're just going to be guessing..